# If $A$ starts the game, show that $P(A \text{ wins}) > \frac{1}{2}$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

The question is:

Two friends A and B are playing a game of flipping a coin with P(head). = p alternatively and whoever gets a head first wins the game. If A starts the game, show that P(A wins) > $\frac{1}{2}$.

So my approach was the following:

A can win in many different ways.  Either A wins on the first toss whose probability is p, or on the second toss whose probability is (1-p)p...... And this is a geometric series, but when I do the summation I get 1. What am I doing wrong?

But I am not exactly sure as to how to use this, or if even my logic is correct.

Comment: $A$ can't win on the second toss.  $B$ wins on all the even numbered tosses.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you aren't asked to compute the probability that $A$ wins; you just need to show that it is bigger than $\frac 12$.

But take any path that leads to a $B$ victory.  We map that to a path leading to an $A$ victory by deleting the initial $T$.  Clearly that process increases the probability of that path. Hence $A$ is more likely to win than $B$ is, and that's all you need.

Of course, it is easy enough to compute it.  Let $\psi$ denote the probability that $A$ wins.  We remark that either $A$ wins on the first toss or else $A$ throws a $T$ in which case $A$ needs for $B$ to also throw a $T$ (in which case the game resets).  It follows that $$\psi=p+(1-p)^2\psi$$ which implies $$\psi=\frac 1{2-p}$$  which is indeed $>\frac 12$  (note that the case $p=0$ is degenerate, in that neither player ever wins.)

Answer (score 0):

You are summing the probability that the $n$th toss is heads and all previous tosses were tails. This doesn't take into account that $B$ is also a player, and so the sum for this is $1$.

Instead what you should be doing is summing the probability that the $(2n-1)$th toss is heads (which would be $A$'s $n$th toss) and all previous tosses were tails. This is the probability that $A$ wins on the $(2n-1)$th toss **and that $B$ didn't throw heads yet**. In this case, the sum would be $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p)^{2n-2}p$$

Can you finish from here?